# Tresses or long hair

Tags: word-request

What do we call the hair that hangs loose on the neck below the ear?
Tresses?

As can be seen in the image:

[image: picture with the hair below the ear circled in red]

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/tresses?q=tressesOxford dictionary says: tresses= a woman’s long hair... What about man's hair of such style?

Answer (score 4):

There's no specific word for hair that hangs loose on the neck below the ear. You would have to describe it just the same way if you were talking or writing about it. I can't think of any words describing hair in any specific position on the head.

'Tresses' refers to a [long locks of hair](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tress) and it is usually used for women's hair. It doesn't refer to hair from any specific part of the head.

Comment: "Tresses" is also something of a literary word which I can't recall ever hearing spoken in conversation.  It does occasionally show up in poetry and song.  I personally would not use it outside of some kind of poetic context.